# How to query on a list by list comprehension and min/max functionalities

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two `Python` classes: `Agent` and `Group`...

Each `Group` has a `centerGroup` property, plus a static list of groups, i.e. `GroupList`

Here is a brief overview of the `Group` class:

```
import Agent

class Group(object):
"""description of class"""

GroupIdentifier = 1
GroupThreshold = 10
GroupList = []


def __init__(self, agentList = None ,groupCenter = None, gruopIdentifier = None):
    global GroupIdentifier
    global GroupList
    self.groupIdentifier = GroupIdentifier
    Group.GroupIdentifier += 1
    Group.GroupList.append(self)
    self.groupCenter = groupCenter
    self.agentList = agentList
```

Furthermore, within the `Agent` class, I am going to find the minimum euclidean distance of a typical agent from all `centerGroup` properties corresponding to the groups in the `groupList`... (There is an offset, is which `GAMMA_TRESHOLD`)...

One can depict the related part of `Agent` class, as below snippet:

```
import Group

class Agent(object):
"""description of class"""

GAMMA_TRESHOLD = 20

def __init__(self, point = None, groupId = None):
    self.locationX = point.x
    self.locationY = point.y
    self.groupId = 0

def get_agent_distance_from_groupCenter(self, object):
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(self.locationX - point.x, 2) +
                     math.pow(self.locationY - point.y, 2))

def gamma_condition(self):
    #I KNOW THIS IMPLEMENTATION IS WRONG... JUST GOTTA SHOW THE TARGET!
    return Group.Group.GroupList[Group.Group.GroupList.index(min(get_agent_distance_from_groupCenter(agent, group.groupCenter) - GAMMA_TRESHOLD))]
```

From a mathematical manner perspective, the problem is minimizing the below norm and introducing the group, which its `centerGroup` is nearest to the agent:

```
min \norm{centerGroup_{i} - agent - TRESHOLD}
```

Would you please helping me to write such query (valid processing for `gamma_condition` method) by list comprehension of `Python`?!

Comment: Wait, don't you have circular dependencies?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso: There it is, actually due to my reluctancy to use inheritance... But it is not my problem and the subject of this question, right now!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in all, with due attention to lack of any better idea from the other people, my investigations lead to below solution for this problem:

```
def gamma_condition(self):
    temp = []
    maxValue = 0
    temp = [[item.groupIdentifier, JOIN_TRESHOLD - self.get_agent_distance_from_groupCenter(item.groupCenter)] for item in Group.Group.GroupList]
    for item in temp:
        maxValue = max(float(i) for i in item[1])
    if maxValue > 0:
        index = temp.index(maxValue)
        NearestGroupIdToJoin = temp[index][0]    
        return NearestGroupIdToJoin
    else:
        return None
```